# Search for unique file in two or more folders

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, search, file-search

Is there a way to search for single/unique files in two or more different folders in windows? is there an add-on/app for this? (Don't understand how to run code)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) will compare two folders for differences if that's what you mean. You can then use the **View** menu to **Show Left Unique Items** and also **Show Right Unique Items**.